# Cannot find a free socket for the debugger in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

when i try to debug the java programe , it says "Cannot find a free socket for the debugger in eclipse".Could you explain how to resolve the error ?

Comment: Please provide a little more info. Are you using Windows? Are you logged on with an administrator account? Sometimes Windows blocks sockets because they could be a security vulnerability - you might need to explicitly allow sockets.

Comment: This happens to me (under Windows) when I don't have a network connection active on my computer. The debugger tries to bind to a network interface that is not up...

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution (at least in my case).

Eclipse was installed on a company share drive once I moved it to my local C drive everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As in this thread, you might want to explicitly mention the [path of the JVM you are using to execute eclipse](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg23766.html).
See this **[`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** as an example.

- [bug 12132](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12132) mentioned incorrect socks proxy information.
- [bug 27654](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27654) refered to a configuration problem ([firewall](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg00847.html), antivirus?)

The usual checks (some are Windows specifics) are:

> - switch off the vista firewall (it wasn't activated, to be precise)
> - add a firewall rule for `java.exe`/`javaw.exe`/`eclipse.exe` and reactivated it (just to be sure it didn't interfere although it was deactivated)
> - deactivated my antivirus tool (avira antivir)
> - ran eclipse as administrator
> - disabled UAC
> - activated/deactivated wired and wireless network interfaces
> - changed priorities of the network interfaces
> - used different jvms (1.6 and 1.7)
> - created an entirely new workspace

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error message when migrating to a virtual Win10 machine (Eclipse 2019-09) as of November 2019.

My solution was as follows:
First, like Dan above, make sure you do not start eclipse.exe from a network drive, but from C:...\eclipse-dir.
After I did this, Windows Defender Firewall came up with a dialogue informing me that it had 'blocked some features of this app' (eclipse.exe). After I pressed the 'Allow access'-Button, I was able to debug as I had been used to.

It appears that you have to add eclipse.exe to the applications that can communicate through Windows Defender Firewall. If you need to do this manually, go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Defender Firewall and choose Allowed apps. Press 'Change settings' and 'Allow another app...' to navigate to your eclipse.exe using the file picker dialogue.